# JavaScript Balance Calculation Issue with Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation, dynamic-tables

I'm encountering an issue with JavaScript where I need to calculate and update balances based on input field values. I've explained my requirements and provided the relevant code, but I'm having trouble getting the calculations to work correctly.

Problem:

I have a table (#toggle_table) that contains payment history, and each row represents a payment made. There's an input field in each row (td.editable-amount-paid input) where users can enter the payment amount. There's also a balance cell in the same row (td.balance-cell) that should update dynamically based on the grand total and the total amount paid so far.

Requirements:

The grand total is obtained from $('#customer_gtotal').val().
Each row should have a balance cell that reflects the difference between the grand total and the total amount paid so far.
When a user edits the payment amount in an input field, the balance cell in the same row and subsequent rows should update accordingly.
The balance cell should be updated in real-time as the user types in the input field.
Issue:

I've attempted to implement this behavior in JavaScript with the following code:

```
 function updateBalances() {
var cumulativePayment = 0;

// Iterate through rows in the table
$('#toggle_table tbody tr').each(function() {
    try {
        var inputField = $(this).find('.editable-amount-paid input');
        var balanceCell = $(this).find('.balance-cell');

        // Get the payment amount for this row
        var paymentAmount = parseFloat(inputField.val()) || 0;

        // Calculate the cumulative payment including the previous balance
        cumulativePayment += paymentAmount;

        // Update the balance cell for this row with the cumulative payment
        balanceCell.text(cumulativePayment.toFixed(2));
    } catch (error) {
        // Log any errors that occur during row updates
        console.error('Error updating row:', error);
    }
});
 }


  $('#toggle_table tbody tr .editable-amount-paid input').on('input', 
  updateBalances);


updateBalances();
```

Eg )
[image: My #toggle_table]

If you change the input field value in the first row to 3000, the following will happen based on the provided code:

The totalAmountPaid will be updated to 3000 (the sum of the new input field value).
The balanceCell in the first row will be updated to 3500 - 3000 = 500
The balanceCell in the second row will be updated to 500 - 1000 = -500.
However, the code is not working as expected. When I change the payment amount in the input field of one row, it doesn't correctly update the balance cell in that row and subsequent rows.

Can someone please review my code and help me identify the issue with the balance calculations? I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to make this functionality work as intended.

Thank you!

UPDATED : My table will be dynamically created by the JS

```
           $('#payment_history').click(function(event) {
          $('#current_in_id').val($('#invoice').val());
          var dataString = {
              dataString: $("#histroy").serialize()
          };
          dataString[csrfName] = csrfHash;

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Cinvoice/payment_history",
              data: $("#histroy").serialize(),

              success: function(data) {

                  var basedOnCustomer = data.based_on_customer;
                  var overallGTotal = parseFloat(data.overall[0].overall_gtotal);
                  var overall_due = parseFloat(data.overall[0].overall_due);
                  var overall_paid = parseFloat(data.overall[0].overall_paid);
                  console.log("OVER : " + overallGTotal);
                  var gt = $('#customer_gtotal').val();
                  var amtpd = data.amt_paid;

                  var bal = $('#customer_gtotal').val() - data.amt_paid;
                  var total = "<table id='table2' class='newtable table table-striped table-bordered'><tbody><tr><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align: middle;text-align-last: center;'><b>Grand Total :  <?php  echo $currency;  ?>" + $('#customer_gtotal').val() + "<b></td><td class='td' style='border-right: hidden;'><b>Total Amount Paid :<b></td><td><?php  echo $currency;  ?><span class='amt_paid_update'><input type='text' value='" + data.amt_paid + "' name='tl_amt_pd'/></span></td><td><input type='hidden' value='" + $('#customer_gtotal').val() + "' name='t_unique'/><span style='font-weight:bold;'>INVOICE NO</span> :<input type='hidden' value='" + $('#invoice').val() + "' name='unq_inv'/>" + $('#invoice').val() + "</td></tr><tr><td class='td' ><b>Balance :<input type='text' value='" + bal + "' name='my_bal_1'/><b></td><td class='due_pay' style='display:none;' id='balance-cell' data-currency='<?php  echo $currency;  ?>'>" + bal + "</td><td  data-currency='<?php echo $currency; ?>'><span style='font-weight:bold;'>Amount to Pay : </span><input type='text' id='amount_pay_unique' class='amount_pay' style='text-align:center;' name='amount_pay_1'/></td><td style='display:none'><input type='text'  value='<?php if($all_invoice[0]['payment_id']){ echo $all_invoice[0]['payment_id']; }else{ echo $payment_id_new;}?>' name='payment_id_this_invoice' class='payment_id_val' id='payment_id'/></td><td style='display:none' class='' data-currency='<?php echo $currency; ?>'><input type='text' name='updated_bal_uniq' class='balance-col'/></td><td> <input type='text' id='total-amount' placeholder='Enter Amount To Distribute'></td></tr></tbody></table>"
                  var table_header = "<div class='toggle-button' onclick='toggleTable()'>Payment History &#9660;</div><table id='toggle_table' class='table table-striped table-bordered'><thead style='FONT-WEIGHT:BOLD;'><tr><td>S.NO</td><td>Payment Date</td><td>Reference.NO</td><td>Bank Name</td><td>Amount Paid</td><td>Balance</td><td>Details</td><td>Action</td></tr></thead><tbody>";

                  // var total = "<table id='table2' class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tr><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align: middle;text-align-last: center;'><b>Grand Total :  <?php  echo $currency;  ?>"+$('#customer_gtotal').val()+"<b></td><td class='td' style='border-right: hidden;'><b>Total Amount Paid :<b></td><td><?php  echo $currency;  ?><span class='amt_paid_update'>"+data.amt_paid+"</span></td><td><span style='font-weight:bold;'>INVOICE NO</span> :"+$('#invoice').val()+"</td></tr></tr><td class='td' style='border-right: hidden;'><b>Balance :<b></td><td id='balance-cell' data-currency='<?php  echo $currency;  ?>'>"+bal +"</td><td><input type='button' value='Make Payment' style='color:white;background-color: #38469f;' class='paypls btn btn-large'></td></tr></table>"
                  // var table_header = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'><thead style='FONT-WEIGHT:BOLD;'><tr><td>S.NO</td><td>Payment Date</td><td>Reference.NO</td><td>Bank Name</td><td>Amount Paid</td><td>Balance</td><td>Details</td><td>Action</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
                  var table_footer = "</tbody></table>";
                  var html = "";
                  var count = 1;

                  data.payment_get.forEach(function(element) {
                      html += "<tr><td>" + count + "</td><td>" + element.payment_date + "</td><td>" + element.reference_no + "</td><td>" + element.bank_name + "</td><td  class='editable-amount-paid' data-currency='<?php echo $currency; ?>'>" + element.amt_paid + "</td><td class='balance-cell' contenteditable='false'>" + element.balance + "</td><td>" + element.details + "</td><td style='display:none;'><input type='hidden'  class='payment_id_val' id='payment_id'/></td><td><button style='color:white;background-color: #38469f;padding:2px;font-weight:bold;' onclick='editRow(this)'>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
                      count++;
                  });

                  var all = total + table_header + html + table_footer;

                  var total1 = "<table id='table1'  class='table 
      table-striped table-bordered'><tr><td colspan='3' 
   style='border-top: hidden!important;background-color: white;text- 
 align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;'>LIST OF DUE 
   INVOICES</td></tr><tr><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align: 
  middle;text-align-last: center;'><b>Grand Total :  <?php  echo 
       $currency;  ?>" + overallGTotal.toFixed(2) + "<b></td><td 
   class='td' style='border-right: hidden;'><b>Total Amount Paid :<b> 
  </td><td><?php  echo $currency;  ?>" + overall_paid.toFixed(2) + " 
     </td></tr></tr><td class='td' style='border-right: hidden;'> 
   <b>Balance :<b></td><td id='balance-cell' data-currency='<?php  
   echo $currency;  ?>'>" + parseFloat(overall_due.toFixed(2)) + " 
  </td></tr></table>"
                  var table_header1 = "<table class='newtable-second 
  table table-striped table-bordered'><thead style='FONT- 
   WEIGHT:BOLD;'><tr><td style='width:10px;'>S.NO</td><td><div 
  id='distribute-container'> </div></td><td 
  style='width:60px;'>Invoice No</td><td style='width:100px;'>Total 
  Amount</td><td style='width:200px;'>Amount Paid</td><td 
  style='width:200px;'>Balance</td><td style='width:200px;'>Amount to 
Pay</td><td class='balance-column' style='width:200px;'>Updated 
 Balance</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
                  var table_footer1 = "</tbody><tfoot><tr><td 
 colspan='6'></td><td class='t_amt_pay'></td><td  
 style='display:none;' class='balance-col t_bal_pay'></td></tr> 
  </tfoot></table>";
                  var html1 = "";
                  var count1 = 1;


                  for (var invoiceId in basedOnCustomer) {
                      if (basedOnCustomer.hasOwnProperty(invoiceId)) 
  {

                          var element = basedOnCustomer[invoiceId];
                          var pay_id = element.payment_id;
                          console.log("PAY :" + pay_id);
                          var random10DigitNumber = '';
                          if (pay_id == '' || pay_id == '0') {
                              random10DigitNumber = 
    generateRandom10DigitNumber();
                          } else {
                              random10DigitNumber = pay_id;
                          }
                          html1 += "<tr><td style='display:none;'> 
        <input type='hidden' value='" + random10DigitNumber + "' 
  name='payment_id[]'/></td><td>" + count1 + "</td><td> <input 
    type='checkbox' id='<?php echo $count1; ?>' class='checkbox- 
   distribute'></td><td><input type='text' readonly style='text- 
   align:center;'  value='" + element.commercial_invoice_number + "' 
  name='invoice_no[]'/></td><td><input type='text' readonly  
  class='g_pament' value='" + element.gtotal + "' name='total_amt[]' 
  style='text-align:center;'/></td><td>" + element.paid_amount + " 
 </td><td class='due_pay' data-currency='<?php echo $currency; ?>'>" 
  + element.due_amount + "</td><td  data-currency='<?php echo 
 $currency; ?>'><input type='text' id='amount_pay' class='amount_pay' 
 style='text-align:center;' name='amount_pay[]'/></td><td    
 class='balance-column' data-currency='<?php echo $currency; ?>'> 
<input type='text' name='updated_bal[]' readonly class='balance- 
col'/></td> 
  </tr>";
                          count1++;
                      }
                  }
                  all += total1 + table_header1 + html1 + 
    table_footer1;
                  var total2 = ""
                  var table_header2 = "<div id='pay_now_table'><table 
   class='table table-striped table-bordered'><tr><th>Date</th> 
   <th>Bank</th><th>Reference No</th><th>Payment Amount</th> 
  <th>Action</th></tr><tr><td><input type='date' 
   name='bulk_payment_date' value='<?php echo html_escape($date); ? 
   >'/></td><td><select name='bulk_bank' id='bank'  class='form- 
  control bankpayment' > <option value='JPMorgan Chase'>JPMorgan 
    Chase</option> <option value='SoFi'>SoFi</option> <?php 
  foreach($bank_list as $b){ ?> <option value='<?=$b['bank_name']; ? 
 >'><?=$b['bank_name']; ?></option> <?php } ?> </select></td><td> 
 <input type='text' name='bulk_pay_ref' placeholder='Ref No'/></td> 
    <td class='t_amt_pay'></td>";
                  var table_footer2 = "<td><input type='submit' 
 style='color:white;background-color: #38469f;padding:2px;font- 
weight:bold;' id='pay_now' value='PAY NOW'/></td></tr></tbody> 
 </table></div>";
                  var html2 = "";
                  var count2 = 1;
                  all += total2 + table_header2 + html2 + 
    table_footer2;

                  $('#salle_list').html(all);
                  $('#payment_history_modal').modal('show');
                  $('#pay_now_table').hide();
                  $('.balance-column').hide();
                  var amountPaidCells = 
    document.querySelectorAll('#salle_list tbody tr td:nth- 
     child(5)'); // Assuming "Amount Paid" is the 5th column
                  amountPaidCells.forEach(function(cell) {
                      cell.addEventListener('input', function() {
                          updateBalances();

                      });
                  });
              }
          });

          event.preventDefault();
      });
```

@Chuck Terry
[image: .editable-amount-paid]

@Swati

```
        <table id="toggle_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="display: table;">
       <thead style="FONT-WEIGHT:BOLD;">
          <tr>
             <td>S.NO</td>
             <td>Payment Date</td>
             <td>Reference.NO</td>
             <td>Bank Name</td>
             <td>Amount Paid</td>
             <td>Balance</td>
             <td>Details</td>
             <td>Action</td>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr data-row-id="unique_row_id_1696080502903">
             <td>1</td>
             <td><input type="text" class="editable-input-1" 
       name="inputField1"></td>
             <td><input type="text" class="editable-input-2" 
             name="inputField2"></td>
             <td><input type="text" class="editable-input-3" 
            name="inputField3"></td>
             <td class="editable-amount-paid" data-currency="$"><input 
              type="text" class="editable-input-4" name="inputField4"> 
      </td>
             <td class="balance-cell" 
              contenteditable="false">500.00</td>
             <td><input type="text" class="editable-input-6" 
        name="inputField6"></td>
             <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" 
             class="editable-input-7" name="inputField7"></td>
             <td><button class="save-button" style="background-color: 
          rgb(56, 70, 159); color: white; font-weight: 
        bold;">Update</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2021-11-15</td>
             <td>0</td>
             <td>JPMorgan Chase</td>
             <td class="editable-amount-paid" data- 
       currency="$">3077.35</td>
             <td class="balance-cell" 
       contenteditable="false">500.00</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" 
        class="payment_id_val" id="payment_id"></td>
             <td><button style="color:white;background-color: 
        #38469f;padding:2px;font-weight:bold;" 
     onclick="editRow(this)">Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

@Chuck Terry

[image]

Comment: first off, can you post your table's html?  Second, out of pure curiosity...  Try replacing your ```if (inputField && balanceCell)``` with a try catch block and just log the error in catch. See if either row updates

Comment: @ChuckTerry..Nothing is found in the console.log

Comment: Thanks for the update, one moment and I'll take a look over it.

Comment: Okay, does ```data.payment_get[element].amt_paid``` contain a dollar amount or an input element with the dollar amount?  If only a dollar amount, remove the input descendent selector from ```var inputField = $(this).find('.editable-amount-paid input');``` and give it a shot.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Thanks for the response ,I thing the link you have provided is entirely different from what i want.

Comment: @ChuckTerry  inputField = $(this).find('.editable-amount-paid input'); . Here i am trying to fetch the input from the td (class='editable-amount-paid'). Please Kind the Snip i have Attached

Comment: Ok, last two questions.  What is the code used by the edit button?  and what is the code used to commit the edit to that input element.  This is likely being caused by listening to the input event when the actual value of the input is being updated programmatically by JS.

Comment: at first the table td will be uneditable ,the edit button is just to make the input field editable to change the amount paid value

Comment: Hi @Surya , Can you add html generated code from browsers element tabs ?

Comment: @Swati Please see the Updated Code i have Attached the HTML generated by JS (#toogle_table)

Comment: Okay, still thinking this is an event related problem.  Jump on Chrome or Edge, load your page, then type ```monitorEvents(window, ['input', 'change']);``` into DevTools.  Edit one of the Balance values, and post the console output in your question.

Comment: @ChuckTerry   I have updated the Console image  .Please find the Uploaded Image